# How do I set a Frame's height equal to its width in C# Markup?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

In Microsoft's Xamarin documentation, they have this example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-self) that shows how to do it with XAML, but I have some frames that I am generating dynamically so I need to be able to do it in C#.

Here is the XAML code to do it, can anyone translate this into C# for me?

```
<BoxView Color="Red"
     WidthRequest="200"
     HeightRequest="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=WidthRequest}"
     HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
<BoxView Color="Red"
 WidthRequest="200"
 HeightRequest="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"
 HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: Please give a little more context, Please bear in mind that some users will not understand, what part of your code solves the problem. 
Remember: Answer questions a little more detailed than you would a decent answer to look like (boyscout rule applied to SO)

Answer (score 2):

Usually in c# you have the value in a variable; simply use that variable for both properties:

```
        int size = 200;
        var view = new BoxView() { WidthRequest = size, HeightRequest = size };
```

If you already have a view with WidthRequest set, then:

```
view.HeightRequest = view.WidthRequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setBinding method(), like code below shows:

```
    var boxview=new BoxView();
    boxview.Color=Color.CornflowerBlue;
    boxview.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    boxview.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    boxview.WidthRequest=100;
    boxview.setBinding(BoxView.HeightProperty,new Binding("WidthRequest"),source:boxview);
```